# Unable to uninstall AnkhSVN 2.3

Tags: ankhsvn

When I tried to uninstall AnkhSVN, it stucks/hangs up with a message saying 0 seconds left. Anyone else encountered this issue? Any suggestion?
I'm running Windows 7 RTM x64 Eng + VS2010 SP1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Again, I have to answer my own question. I'll try to describe the process of fixing it, too.
First thing I thought of is to google a solution, but with no success. Then I tried Revo Uninstaller, again to a deadend. Then I noticed that when uninstall AnkhSVN, a devenv.exe process showed up, I suddenly realize that this was OUR HITLER. So after killing the process with Task Manager, the uninstall proceeded and succeeded.

Bravo.

But this indeed took sometime to do. I spent about 2 to 3 hours on this.

Also this method fixed the issue that installing of AnkhSVN 2.4 (the latest) hangs up when registering with Visual Studio 2010. Just kill devenv.exe and everything works fine.

Comment: Visual Studio needs a call to devenv.exe /setup to complete adding or removing components. This allows all extensions to handle setup tasks. Killing this might break your install until it completes once.  would recommend starting this yourself as administrator and checking with a debugger which component stalls this process. (Most likely it is not AnkhSVN, as that is gone at the time it gets run from the AnkhSVN uninstall)

Comment: @BertHuijben, I know it's kind of dangerous, but I waited more than 30 minutes before killing the devenv.exe process, so I guess I'm relatively safe. I guess it's not AnkhSVN too since I'm having the same issue with latest KB installation too. About how to debug, could you be a bit specific? I took advice from Scott Hanselman that we should dig a little deep. That's why I looked in the Task Manager in the first place.